# Gwt Error with no clear explanation?

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

In my application, I have 2 type of objects: the first only has a Label Key whereas the second has a Label Key and a Version which act as a Key for the object. When launching a edit page for the first type of object, I get a wierd exception with no details related to the cause but when I launch the edit page for the second type of objects, it runs correcly.

I am getting the following exception:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cet objet ne gère pas cette propriété ou cette méthode (Translation :Object does not support this property or method)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can you please attach the relevant code so we can help you debug?

Comment: Sorry, The code is more than 3000 lines and is Confidential. I was able to solve it by using Google Chrome which presented the error in another form and I was able to solve it. Thanks anyway for your efforts

Comment: @AdelBoutros: If you found a solution, you should try to post it as an answer to your own question. This will help people encountering the same error and finding this page on Google. Plus, you might earn a nice badge for it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is simple:
**Do Not Test in Internet Explorer.**
By using Google Chrome, I got a more specific and clear exception about what was causing the problem.